# How to use ESP_LOGx?

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, logging

I can't get the logging to work on the ESP32.
Here is my example:

```
#define LOG_LOCAL_LEVEL ESP_LOG_VERBOSE
#include <esp_log.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ESP_LOGE("Test", "This is a test!");
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  ESP_LOGE("Test", "This is a repesting test!");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Serial.print");
  delay(1000);
}
```

It only prints `Serial.print` every two seconds, but not the log messages.

Comment: Without any experience but after rushing through the documentation: Don't you need to call [`esp_log_level_set()`](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/log.html#_CPPv417esp_log_level_setPKc15esp_log_level_t)?

Comment: You can set the log level from the Arduino IDE via Tools -> Core Debug Level. By default it is set to NONE.

Comment: I just had to add my thanks to hcheung! Changing the `#defines` and using `esp_log_level_set()` made no apparent difference. Setting Core Level Debug made all the difference, seeming to override the #defines mentioned above. -- John B

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to hcheung! I had to set the `Core Debug Level` in the `Tools` menu.